# how do i send data from a php file on a remote web host to a c# application on my computer?

Tags: c#, php

I am working on a c# wpf application that will need to receive communication from my web server. the user would enter some details on the website which will be using php/html forms. when they click submit on the form it needs to send data from the form to the c# application. the wpf application will open the php web page so if i need to send some form of identification when opening the page i can handle that with post variables. just not sure how to get the data back to the wpf app

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the C# is a file that you can execute from the command line, or one that you can turn into that:

shell_exec();  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

or backticks:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: the c# will be open and running pretty much the entire time that the php file will need to send data to it. the c# application and the php file will not be on the same machine.

Comment: Well, then you're going to have to put a web server of some kind in front of C#.  One way or another, you'll need C# connected to a listening port.  One workaround would be to implement the answer I offered above by putting an Apache server on the computer with C# so that you can have PHP there as well.  However, if the C# program is the client (user software, not a server), then you'll probably need to turn this around so that your C# program is just asking the server (PHP code) for updates at regular intervals.